# How to use Memoise in R

Tags: r, caching, scope, do.call, memoise

I have been trying to use memoise to speed up computations for a function I wrote.

In a nutshell, I have a function `a()` that performs `do.call()` on another function `b()`.
function `b()` runs code to read files over the past year and then performs some calculations.

So if you wanted to run `a()` for 1/12/2019, 2/12/2019, 3/12/2019, `b()` is going to read files for one year prior to 1/12, 2/12, 3/12. E.g. Files read for 1/12/19 would be between 1/12/18 to 1/12/19, files read for 2/12/2019 would be between 2/12/2018 and 2/12/2019. Essentially, there will be a lot of overlap in the files that `b()` reads. so it would essentially be ideal to memoise an `fread()` function that `b()` uses.

I have written a sample function below

```
b<-function(){

##ideally would want to memoise it this way

if(!is.memoised(fread))

##fread=memoise(fread)

fread(...)
}
a<-function(){
do.call(b())
}
```

So I have discovered after many painful hours that this does not work in theory as the memoisation function has a constraint relating to how many times it can be called - i.e. if it is called more than once then it does not remember the previous function parameters that were used by the previously memoised `fread()`, essentially eliminating the usefulness of the function)

1. I suspect it has something to do with the scope of the memoised function, everytime `b()` is called it is memoising fread again
2. I tried to implement `<<-` for memoising fread, but I think I did not implement it the right way as it threw an error saying 'could not modify fread'
3. Would memoising `fread` in the global environment help? Again, I was not able to implement it the right way
4. is there something drastically long in the way i am thinking about these functions and memoisation?

Any input would be appreciated.